# vue-cli 3 не правильно создаёт проект

Tags: vue.js

Я делал всё по видео уроку от Vue. Делал всё медленно и последовательно. На одном из шагов, автор после создания проекта `vue create app-name`, запустил команду `npm run serve` и запустил локальный сервер с шаблоном проекта от Vue.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня же на этом шаге команда не сработала, более того, папка проекта пополнилась только двумя файлами конфигурации, хотя в примере было добавлено огромное количество различных модулей и тд.

[image: Мой проект после создания]

Я запутался и не знаю что делать. Очень хочется попробовать это в работе, но столкнулся с проблемой, решения которого найти не могу. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Покажите ещё, пожалуйста, вывод команды `vue create app-name` (но уже желательно с другим app-name)

Comment: Спасибо что ответили, я уже решил проблему. Не знаю в чём было дело, но я просто скачал VS Code и запустил команду там, и ... всё сработало:D
Я не знаю с чем это связано)